# Figure shows up in another subsection

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to add two figures in subsection 2 , only with some text between the figures. The problem is that one picture shows up in the correct place, while the other shows up in the next subsection. What can I do to make them show up one after another in the same subsection.

Here is the Latex template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{longtable,geometry}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs


\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}








\begin{document}

\section*{SECTION} 

\subsection*{SUBSECTION 1}
BLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA

BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA


BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA


BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABL
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\



\subsection*{SUBSECTION 2}
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG


    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{picture1.jpg} 
    \caption{CAPTION HERE}
    \end{figure}

IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT
IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT
IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT

    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{picture2.jpg} 
    \caption{CAPTION 2 HERE}
    \end{figure}


\subsection*{SUBSECTION 3}
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND

THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND

THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)

Comment: Do you know package `lipsum` and `blindtext`? Please have a look at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `placins` and `\FloatBarrier` might be of use here!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{longtable,geometry}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % Uncomment to remove all indentation from paragraphs


\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}








\begin{document}

\section*{SECTION} 

\subsection*{SUBSECTION 1}
BLABLABLABLABLA BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA

BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA


BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA


BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABL
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\
BLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLABLA\\



\subsection*{SUBSECTION 2}
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG
DILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONGDILIDINGDILIDONG


    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ente.jpg} 
    \caption{CAPTION HERE}
    \end{figure}

IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT
IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT
IFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHATIFTHISTHENTHAT

    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{ente.jpg} 
    \caption{CAPTION 2 HERE}
    \end{figure}


\FloatBarrier
\subsection*{SUBSECTION 3}
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND

THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND

THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
THEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEENDTHEEND
\end{document}
```